# Add-Contacts in each user accounts django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, contacts

Hey guys I have created a messanging app in django in which i have User.auth,Profile and message app which works fine. Now i need is to add contact category in every user accounts. So they can add contacts like email with there firstname and last name?

Comment: And what have you tried? What don't you understand?

Comment: not tried because i have no idea how to implement this theory into machine code.so little help is make me go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to update your Profile model to include a many-to-many relationship with other Users. Then you can access the related user models for a given profile's contacts through that profile. In the profile model:

```
contacts = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

Set blank/null as is appropriate.